# How to stop css stylesheet from being automatically modified on branch checkout?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, core-ui

On my work project, every time I check out a branch, the style.css file is modified. No one on our team has been able to find out why.

At first I thought it had something to do with What the terminal tells me after I git stash these changes. It says something about LF vs CRLF line endings. So I toggled that configuration in vs code but it made no difference.

There’s no code I can think about including in this. I don’t even know where to start.

I expect it to not change any files when I check out a branch. But instead it always modified the file, and actually changes the stylesheet to different values that I can’t figure out where they’re coming from.

Comment: Is your css code generated? What changes occur? Does it always happen with any user or is it random?

Comment: Yes the style.css file is auto-generated. We use Sass. It changes the version number of core-UI we’re using and a bunch of other values throughout it. It happens with anyone on our team.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but guessing you're using git and between your team members you have folks using a mix of Windows and Mac / *nix systems and you just need to [configure crlf formatting](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings) in git itself, not the IDE.

Comment: @ChrisW. you’re right, we are using git. All our members are using windows though. I will give that a try, but I don’t think that explains why the style.css file is getting values changed.

Comment: It does though, that's the part about the "something about LF vs CRLF line endings", either that or I'd guess someone has one of those css pretty-fier plugins set to act on save. Either way if you're using git, you can go check the commits and find the culprit pretty quick. 

Comment: Well it explains line endings being changed, but it doesn’t explain why a css attribute like display would change from hidden to visible or a margin size from 5px to 10px. We use prettier on save, but that doesn’t modify files you’re not in.

Comment: My current thinking is that it's a webpack thing, maybe CoreUI's css is remote, and webpack is pulling the latest or something.